# Why used storage of datanodes in Hadoop showed on Web UI fluctuates over time?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Today I loaded data in to my Hadoop cluster and I noticed that the amount of used storage of datanodes in Hadoop showed on Web UI (http://hadoopmaster:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-datanode) fluctuates over time. That means, even though data is loaded in to the cluster continuously but 'Used' column on the Web UI sometimes increases dramatically but sometimes drops sharply.

Why does this happen?

[image: Used column fluctuates (up and down over time)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Files with a replication factor > 1 are not replicated instantly, and takes a while to establish the target replication.
2. As processing happens, you might end up temporarily with many smaller files. However, even though file content is small, they might still take up a lot of space to the set block size. Block size is typically set to a pretty high value, giving more overhead to smaller files. As these smaller files get cleaned up, you will see a drastic decrease in usage.
3. Block pool might shrink as it stays unused for prolonged time. Again, blocks might be pretty big in size.